# Use your own library with JNA on Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface, jna

I am currently creating a project in **Android Studio** which calls a Native C++ Library using **JNA**.

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna,

I downloaded the **libjnidispatch.so** from https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/lib/native/android-x86-64.jar,

I added the **jna.jar** library to my Android Studio project,

I extracted the **libjnidispatch.so** library to put it into the folder **x86_64** on my **jniLibs** directory,

I called the printf() function,

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library
{
    //---libjnidispatch---
    void printf(String format, Object... args);
}
...
   CLibrary demo = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
   demo.prinft("Hello JNA !");
...
```

It ran successfully.

```
Hello JNA !
```

Then, I wanted to use my own library.

I loaded it the same way like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somme(int a, int b)
    return a+b;
```

I compiled it like this (showing gcc on linux here):

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC foo.c
gcc -shared -o foo.so foo.o
```

Java:

```
package com.example.guest.essai2;

        import com.sun.jna.Library;
        import com.sun.jna.Native;
        import com.sun.jna.Platform;

        import android.*;
        import com.google.android.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleApiClient client;

    //--------------JNA----------------------
    public interface Foo extends Library
    {
        //--foo----
        int somme(int a, int b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "/home/guest/workspace/MyApplication/Essai2/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/");
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("foo", "/home/guest/workspace/MyApplication/Essai2/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/");
        Native.register(Foo.class,"foo");

        Foo foo = (Foo) Native.loadLibrary("foo", Foo.class);

        String msg = ""+foo.somme(2,3);
        tv.setText(msg);
        setContentView(tv);
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

I then tried to change the jna.library.path with severals attempts :

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "/home/guest/workspace/MyApplication/Essai2/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/");

NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("foo", "/home/guest/workspace/MyApplication/Essai2/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/");

Native.register(Foo.class,"foo");
```

But each time, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'foo': Native library (android-x86-64/libfoo.so) not found in resource path (.)
```

In spite of the fact that the **libfoo.so** and the **libjnidispatch.so** libraries are in the same path.

So far, I am stuck. Is there someone out there who managed to make android studio work with JNA and a custom C++ library.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Run with the system property `jna.debug_load=true` and JNA will emit debugging information about where it's looking for your library.

Comment: Could you please point me out where those options are in Android Studio ?

Comment: I think, allready is done
I checked my file **studio64.vmoptions**, and I have:

`-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true`

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to search `/home/guest/workspace/MyApplication/Essai2/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/` from within the app code?

Comment: I try this method: http://imagej.net/Developing_using_native_libraries

Comment: It's said here:
**Specifying library search paths**
"If you want to use a library that is not installed in one of the locations your platform looks for libraries by default, you may need to tell JNA where to find the library:"
`NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("opencv", "C:\\opencv");
OpenCV openCV = (OpenCV)NativeLibrary.loadLibrary("opencv", OpenCV.class);`

Comment: I apologize for my poor english, and for my lack of skills, but I am a complete Android-Studio/Java newbie

Comment: That documentation _does not apply_ to android development.  Android requires you bundle the natives with your app in a very platform-specific way.

Comment: Have you an idea about the way to bundle that with Android Studio ?
I tried a lot of methods but I didn't find the correct one for Android Studio _x86_64_.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether JNA works on android at all. Samuel Audet (Author of javaCV) tried to port it once however the patch wasn't included into the official JNA trunk. There is still a version [online](https://github.com/netjunki/jna-android) (which you can check out). You can read the details [here](https://github.com/netjunki/jna-android/blob/master/android.txt)...
And there is a discussion about it:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11099
Were in the end they suggest using [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp).

Comment: Thank you very much, I was starting to despair.
I will follow your suggestions and try JavaCPP !

Answer (score 0):

The command you used to build the library, `gcc -shared -o .so foo.o`, compiles it to a file named ".so", try `gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I ommited it in my first message (I corrected it).

Comment: @Lud23 Does `libfoo.so` placed under `android-x86-64` directory?

Comment: But the class loader is trying to search it at `android-x86-64/libfoo.so`. So you need to add that path to the search path.

Comment: Amongst, the numerous attempts I made, I tried both `android-x86-64` `x86_64` and neither worked.

What's bothers me most, is that I have been unable to find a single  complete and working sample project using JNA on Android Studio. Could you point me toward one please ?